# Button event fires first time on one server but not the other

Tags: xpages

We have a Dev, QA and Prod environment.  Other than the fact that Pistolstar is running in QA and prod there seem to be no differences in versions of Notes, OS etc between the 3 environments. I am still working to confrim this.

I am having an issue with events on buttons not firing on click  the first time (I have not checked other types of events)  after the page is displayed.  Button works just fine in Dev but not QA.   It is the same code.

```
Value: <xp:text escape="true" id="ValueField"></xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Set Random Value" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#  {javascript:getComponent("ValueField").setValue(@Random() * 100);}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

If button is pressed a second time in QA then it continues to work.  Works first time every time in Dev.

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Comment: check actual response of event via Firebug - Network. if my events fail to trigger, it is common authentication issue (premature logoff combined with SSO fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are about 99.9% certain that this is a Pistolstar issue.  We are currently working with Pistolstar tech support to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure.

- Are you using the same browser,
- same version of it on all environments?
- Did you sign everything correctly?

Comment: As I am working with Bruce, I can assure you that we are using the same browser, same version of everything on all servers and everything is signed.

This has to be the most frustrating thing we have found yet but we are pretty sure we have narrowed it down to PistolStar. It seems that with PistolStar until you actually perform an action on the page, you are not officially logged in. 

To get around this, we forced the user to login on the page and the button worked correctly the first time it was clicked.

Comment: Yes it does appear to be a Pistolstar issue.  If you go to the page direct the issue occurs.  But there is a page with a link to create the page with the field.  If you go to that page (and you must do it by only specifying the DB in the URL and not the actual page) then the problem goes away when the link is clicked on to create the problem page.  What is strange is that @Username returns a value so I would think you would need to be logged in for xPages to know who you are.